# Php, How to show error for simple blank form submission?

Tags: php, forms

Form html
Is there any way to make the from more secure?

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="example" type="text">
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Php Code

How to show error msg is somebody submits blank

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $example = $_POST['example'];
    function myfunction() {
          $names = array(
              "sumon",
              "bamon",
              "timon",
          );
          return $names[rand ( 0 , count($names) -1)];
     }

     for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
         echo $example.myfunction();
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: why simple don't use `required` in form html?

Comment: _"Is there any way to make the from more secure?"_ - In what sense? What's insecure about it?

Comment: "more secure"... But you're asking then how to stop people sending blank data. Just for the avoidance of confusion in future, what you're asking for here is validation. Validation is not the same as security.

Comment: Do Some front end Validation:
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
  <input name="example" type="text" required>
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

Also do some backend validation:

if (empty($_POST["example"])) {
               $error = "Example is required";
            }else {
               $example = test_input($_POST["example"]);
            }

Answer (score 1):

Just check if `example` input is blank like the `submit`

```
if ( isset($_POST['example']) && $_POST['example'] == "" ) {
    // example input is empty
    die("example input is empty");
}
```

`isset($_POST['example'])` will check if `example` key in exists in `$_POST` array

and then `$_POST['example'] == ""` will check if `example` input is empty

Comment: `isset` doesn't check for emptiness. And this POST variable will indeed be *set* as `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please use the below sample validation . 
     
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = "";
    $name = $email = "";
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        if (empty($_POST["name"]))
        {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        }
        else
        {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        }
    
        if (empty($_POST["email"]))
        {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        }
        else
        {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
    
    }
    
    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    ?>

   <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```